# Route audio through bluetooth ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, bluetooth

I need some help from you ....

I have an app for VoIP calling and i need to route audio of call through bluetooth even in background (in case someone press home button while call is in progress ).. Do i need to set anything in info.plist file in background modes ??

[image]

This is what i have been set for background modes to use bluetooth and apple rejected app with given reason below :

2.16 Details

Your app declares support for bluetooth-central, and bluetooth-peripheral, in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but does not provide Bluetooth Low Energy functionality. The Bluetooth Background modes are for applications that communicate to other devices using Bluetooth Low Energy and the Core Bluetooth framework.

Next Steps

Please revise your app to add support for Bluetooth Low Energy communication through Core Bluetooth in your application or remove the bluetooth- values from the UIBackgroundModes key.

Please help me out .... 
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: how u handling the bluetooth in ur voip app? could u tell some more info about it, im facing issue in bluetooth enabling, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are not using core Bluetooth functions in your app.Just check "Audio and Airplay" and "Voice over IP" check boxes under Background Modes and resubmit the app.

Comment: ok .. I have submitted my app with your configuration lets see its accepted or not ...
Thanks a lot ... and which library you have used for VoIP ??

Comment: can you teach me  ??? I have used pjsip and any licence to purchase for linphone  ?

Comment: You are from which place ?

Comment: You can add me on skype .

Comment: @vivekDas

i have required your help for pjsip Bluetooth for ios.call voice not hear in Bluetooth i  have used following lines for enable pjsip bluethooth:
pjmedia_aud_dev_route route = PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_ROUTE_BLUETOOTH;
        pj_status_t status =
        pjsua_snd_set_setting(PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_INPUT_ROUTE, &route,
                              PJ_TRUE);
always get status 420008.
incoming call ring hears in Bluetooth but after answer call voice not hear.
so have you any solution then please help me.

Comment: @shraddhakvaishanani did you find fixes of incoming calls answered using Bluetooth in linphone?